# How to see the sql query in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

I have a site developed in cakephp 2.0 and I want to see, when I make a query into my controller, the query to the database like: "SELECT * FROM products;"
Is possible to trace the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/) or in your layout add:

```
echo $this->element('sql_dump');
```